# How can I draw rulers in a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a JPanel that contains an image. I want to draw rulers on the JPanel's borders. How can it be done or where should I look for some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Scroll panes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) can only use their own [custom decorations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#decorations). There's information on the official site, maybe you can use this?

[image]
<sub>(source: [sun.com](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/figures/uiswing/components/ScrollDemo.png))</sub>

Comment: did you found this example source on the sun site ?

Comment: Here http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#ScrollDemo